# Mac M1 C++20: Missing std::convertible_to and std::forward_iterator concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, apple-m1

I'm trying to compile a quite big school project on a Mac M1 and I'm facing some missing concept problem.

The project has not really been thought for arm compilation, but I'm trying to see if it would be possible.

I passed the first step: the configure script runs as expected and generate a Makefile as expected.

The problem appears during compilation of some files of the project: clang seems to be missing some standard library concepts (c++20). I have 2 errors about missing concepts: std::convertible_to and std::forward_iterator.

After some research, I found that the apple version of clang for M1 chips does not fully implements all the c++20 features and I think it is the problem I'm facing.

Is there any other compiler for the AArch64 architecture that implements more features of the modern versions of C++ or should I give up now ?

Comment: https://youtu.be/Rk2NOee4D7o something like this?

Comment: Ouch, this seems tricky. I will watch that and give it a try

Comment: I didn't saw the full video, but I think this is not quite what I'm searching for. Transpilling could be a solution for missing std classes but I don't think this is applicable to advanced features like concepts as there is nothing in previous c++ version that can represent this feature in another way

Comment: Have you tried gcc?

Comment: Actually I thought there were no gcc version for m1 mac but that's false, there is one in homebrew repositories.
I installed it but now I can not figure out how to specify to configure/make what compiler to use.
I tried setting the CC / CXX variable before launching ./configure or make: configure seems to be aware of that variable but then the makefile still uses the system alias of g++ wich points to clang++

Comment: You transpile the entire program, then compile the program and run the exe.  Concepts has no runtime meaning, so its erasure during transpiling isn't a problem.  It isn't easy, but it is a plausible way forward.

Comment: For a complete pre-built solution, compile your c++ to wasm, use https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt/tree/master/wasm2c to compile wasm to c, compile c to binary on m1 system.  This will require compiling your own c++ standard library on m1 or the like, so maybe not complete.

Answer (score 2):

> After some research, I found that the apple version of clang for M1 chips does not fully implements all the c++20 features and I think it is the problem I'm facing.

You may want to try Clang from Homebrew(or compile one by yourself). And you can check its implemented features on Clang's offical website.

```
❯ clang++ --version
Homebrew clang version 13.0.0
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin

❯ cat test.cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <iterator>
static_assert(std::convertible_to<char, int>);
static_assert(std::forward_iterator<char*>);

❯ clang++ -std=c++20 -c test.cpp

❯
```

Comment: That does not work for me:
`
$> /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ --version
Homebrew clang version 13.0.1
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin

`

Compiling your small test program gives me the same errors than apple clang

Comment: My bad, I forgot to specify -std=c++20. Now that also fails but with an "undefined symbol for architecture arm64" error...

Comment: @JM445 I guess that you just missed `-c`. Add "-c" flags when running clang or add a empty `main` function to your cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

Please remember that C++20 is still quite fresh and it is very big change to the standard (IMO bigger change then C++11). As a result support of some C++20 features is limited and varies between compilers. It will take couple years to have descent support of this standard.

Here is site which lists current status of C++20 features, for different compilers:

[Compiler support for C++20 - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20#C.2B.2B20_library_features)

> | C++20 feature | Paper(s) | GCC libstdc++ | Clang libc++ | MSVC STL | Apple Clang |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | [Concepts library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts) | [P0898R3](https://wg21.link/P0898R3) | 10 | 13 | 19.23* | 12.0.0* (partial) |

So as you can see, Apple clang is a bit behind in supporting concepts library.

Comment: Yes, I know there are missing features on the apple clang compiler. My question was about finding an alternative that already implements theses features

Comment: I think it is possible to use `libstdc++`  with clang, this should do the trick.