# std::integral not found in clang13 c++20 error

Tags: c++, c++20, concept

i try to learn c++20 concepts my compiler version is "Clang 13" i try to compile very simple code block but i got errors following.

"error: no type named 'floating_point' in namespace 'std'"
"error: no type named 'integral' in namespace 'std'"

i try gcc 11.2 version also but i got same error.

my build commands is following;

clang++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++20 -g -Iinclude -Llib src/main.cpp -o bin/main
clang++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++2a -g -Iinclude -Llib src/main.cpp -o bin/main

Code

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <concepts>
    #include <vector>
     
    
    auto addUnconstrained = [](auto fir, auto sec){ return fir + sec; };
    
    std::floating_point auto addConstrained(std::integral auto fir, 
                                            std::floating_point auto sec){
         return fir + sec;
    }
    
    int main() {
        std::cout << "Hello Easy C++ project!" << std::endl;
    
        std::cout << addUnconstrained(2000, 11.5);    // 2011.5
        std::cout << addConstrained(2000, 11.5);  // 2011.5
    }
```

i will be very appreciate if anyone help me.

thanks

Comment: Can you compile with `-v` and show the output?

Comment: hi output of compiling with "-v" following link. https://gist.github.com/RamazanDemirci/c43db2743792a5afa5b297456c03a423

Comment: The regular Clang 13 should have this feature, but Apple Clang 13 (which is based on Clang 12) might not.

Comment: It seems Apple Clang 13.1.6 should have this. Or download the regular Clang.

Comment: then i have to get 13.1.6 version of clang. i try this

Comment: i can not find 13.1.6  version. after brew install llvm command i got following output "Warning: llvm 13.0.1_1 is already installed and up-to-date." there is clan14 version but i can not install which version with brew. i don`t know how can i install llvm14

Comment: You don't have to use Clang 14. 13 is enough, assuming it's the regular clang and not apple clang. I'm not familiar with MacOS though, so not sure how to install it.

Comment: I think that the apple version of clang for M1 chips does not fully implements all the c++20 features like concept. because i get result with concept and some feature of concepts occur errors like std::integral. i got following page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71370831/mac-m1-c20-missing-stdconvertible-to-and-stdforward-iterator-concepts

i stop reseach on this issue because. thanks @HolyBlackCat

Answer (score 1):

> output of compiling with "-v" following link. gist.github.com/RamazanDemirci/c43db2743792a5afa5b297456c03a423
>
> ```
> Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
> InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
> ```

You were using the Apple Clang. Its implementation for concepts is [not completed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20).

> after brew install llvm command i got following output "Warning: llvm 13.0.1_1 is already installed and up-to-date."

If you have installed llvm-13 from Homebrew, run `brew info llvm` to find where it is installed. For my case, the command outputs

```
If you need to have llvm first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Then I can use `/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang++`. I also prepended the path into `$PATH` so that I can use `clang++` directly to run it instead of Apple Clang.

Run with `--version` to check if it is regular/upstream Clang(the one from homebrew) or Apple Clang.

```
❯ /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ --version
Homebrew clang version 13.0.1
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin
```